# fade a page in with jquery after a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

with this jquery i can fade the page in after it loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('body').hide().fadeIn(1000);
});
</script>
```

now what i want to do is have it that function happen after a button is clicked. for example, when the user goes to the page, there would be a window with a clickable button. after the button was clicked then it would do that fade in jquery loading the page with a fade in.
i was thinking that it would be some kind of form, but the problem is it needs to hide the body when the page is loaded, and then fade in to the body after the button is clicked.

EDIT: i have something like this, however it wont load properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
    $('bodycontent').hide();
});

function loadp(){
    $(function(){
    $('body').hide();
    $('bodycontent').fadeIn(1000);
     });
}   
</script>
```

and for the body and body content

```
<body>
<button onclick="loadp()">Try it</button>
</body>
<bodycontent>
codehere
</bodycontent>
```

theoretically that is supposed to hide the body and fade the bodycontent in after the button is clicked. however the body is hidden but the bodycontent is not loaded.

Comment: Than logically you should not go with `body` but rather with some `#bodyContent`

Comment: the question is how would i activate the function when the button is clicked.

Comment: ok, but makes no sense to ancually fadeIn `body` where you have that button. Take a look at my answer, and correct me if I got something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ILAPAtoK/2/edit)**

```
<button id="fadeContent">OK, fade!</button>

<div id="bodyContent">    
    <h1>Page</h1>
    <p>Content</p>      
</div>
```

```
#bodyContent{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;      left;0;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background:#cf5;
}
```

```
$(function() {

  $('#fadeContent').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('#bodyContent').fadeIn(1000);
  });

});
```

Comment: i got this to work, but instead of having the faded in part being a div i faded it from a tag. "<bodycontent>"

Comment: @riyoken watch out what you're doing. `bodycontent` is not a valid tag therefore you'll have issues with validation and other trouble. Do it like I did it. Simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

this is a fiddle of how i did it: http://jsfiddle.net/VTD9k/
the point is that you put the content inside a div inside the body : `#main-wraper`,
and the button in another div